# Object doesn't support property or method 'menu' JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I want to create a menu from existing UL in a massive html file in the index.html...the code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Menu - Default functionality</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"> </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ui-menu { width: 150px; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Engineer.Com</a></li>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">HHT General</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Uploading Results</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sync Issues</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="">Test Results</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">HHT</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">EXFO</a></li>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Earthing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sync Issues</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Test Heads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Training</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Updates</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="">HHT General</a></li>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Calibration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contractors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">HHT Scripts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Remote Assist</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Standards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sync Issues</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ToC Process</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Training</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Updates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Uploading Results</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="">JDSU</a></li>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Modules</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sync Issues</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="">Process</a></li>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Process</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="">Stores</a></li>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="">Test Results</a></li>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Earthing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Modules</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Test Heads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">EXFO</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Sync Issues</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">HHT General</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Remote Assist</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">JDSU</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Process</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Updates</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Test Results</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Uploading Results</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                        </ul>

            </ul>

        <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Eclipse</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">ToC Process</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">FastTest2</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Process</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">DCoE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">ToC Process</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                        </ul>

            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Quality</a></li>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">FVR</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Contractors</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Process</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Contractors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Standards</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Quality Standards</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Contractors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Standards</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Test Resutls</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                        </ul>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Stores</a></li>
            <ul>
                        <li><a href="">HHT General</a></li>
                                <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
                                </ul>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test System</a></li>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Eclipse</a></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Inventory Failures</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a href="">FastTest2</a></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a href="">Inventory</a></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Inventory Failures</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a href="">Test Results</a></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Inventory Failures</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Test Heads</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">DCoE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Improvements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Night Routining</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">OLID</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Results</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Test Heads</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
                            </ul>
                </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Stores</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Ordering</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Amplifiers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
                        </ul>

            </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I call the menu function in the menu.js file it gives error at run-time:

my menu.js file contains nothing other than document ready function:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#menu').menu({ 

        });
    });
```

Any ideas?

---

Thank you all for your over whelming response...

I have downloaded the package but it has too many files...

I have tried jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js and jquery.ui.menu.js but it still not converting my UL list to menu... Am i missing anything else?

This is the order of my script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"> </script>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a magical `menu()` method, what exactly are you trying to call ? If it's the `menu()` in jQuery UI, you should probably include it !

Comment: You need to include jQuery UI in your project.

Comment: Also, did you really need to post your entire code? In future please create a small demo of your problem.

Comment: What error can you see in the console now ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't load any other js than jQuery.js and menu.js. No method menu is given by jquery.

Maybe you thought about the .menu() jQuery **UI** method.

http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Comment: it could be another plugin also other than jQueryUI, just because one plugin has that method doesn't mean it is the one OP had in mind